# Upper bound via standard manipulation in proof of semi-private learning

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, machine-learning, upper-bound, differential-privacy

I have been reading a paper on private learning [1].
In the proof of lemma 3.3. they claim that
$$
2\left(\frac{2e n_\text{pub}}{d}\right)^{2d}e^{-\alpha n_\text{pub}/4}
$$
is upper bounded by $\beta$ via standard manipulation when $n_\text{pub}=O\left(\frac{d\log(1/\alpha)+\log(1/\beta)}{\alpha}\right)$, $\alpha, \beta \in (0, 1)$, and $d>0$ is an integer. This step is essential in proving that an algorithm achieves semi-private learning. However, I do not see why this value is upper bounded by $\beta$. Any help as to why this is the case would be greatly appreciated. I have tried setting $n_\text{pub}$ to different values that satisfy $n_\text{pub}=O\left(\frac{d\log(1/\alpha)+\log(1/\beta)}{\alpha}\right)$, but I still can't seem to make it work.

1. [Limits of Private Learning with Access to Public Data](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.11519) by N. Alon et al (2019, 25 Oct)

Comment: Alright @D.W. I have added a better citation of the paper now.